# Time in Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been trying to program an app where you can put in a time and a task you want to do, and as soon as the time has "arrived", it Will print out that you have to do this task. This is what I have already:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class task {
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    String taskname;
    DateTimeFormatter timecheck = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    public task()
    {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime currenttime = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println("Name of the task:");
        taskname=scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Time at which you want to do that task:");
        LocalDateTime timeofthetask = LocalDateTime.parse(scanner.next());
        if(currenttime==timeofthetask)
        {
            System.out.println("It's time to do the task"+taskname);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the main class, I have something very simple that basically just runs this class:

```
public class MainClass
{   
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        task t1=new task();
    }
}
```

As soon as I run this, everything goes really smooth, until I try to put in a time, where an error appears as soon as I run the code. The error is called java.time.format.DateTimeParseException, does anybody know what I can do against this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since parse() code is susceptible to throw an exception you should enclose the call into a try catch.

Then, your code works perfectly well, but you need to enter the time in this format:

2007-12-03T10:15:30

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

If you want another format then you will need a formatter.